# nested routing in cakephp, associated model

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I have two associated models (meetings and departments). A meeting has exactly one department, a department many meetings.

I want to expose this association with a restful URL, such as for instance

```
myapp/departments/mydepartmentid/meetings/ 
myapp/departments/mydepartmentid/meetings/mymeetingid 
myapp/departments/mydepartmentid/meetings/add
```

One thing is to configure the routing so that the right actions are called in the meeting controller, but I also would like the HTMLhelper to create links that expose the association, e.G the link should be

```
myapp/departments/mydepartmentid/meetings/mymeetingid
```

when I link to a meeting.

How can I do this?

thanks

Kurt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a Meeting should belongsTo a Department. If you configure the routes correctly, HtlpHelper should work automatically.

```
Router::connect('/departments/:dept_id/meetings', array('controller' => 'meetings','action'=>'index'));
Router::connect('/departments/:dept_id/meetings/:action/*', array('controller' => 'meetings'));
```

You can get to :dept_id somewhere in $this->params['dept_id'] in the controller. For the HtmlHelper use 'dept_id'=>$some_id in the options array.

Comment: ok, thanks. Your route makes this following URL work. myapp/departments/1/meetings/index . However, I seem to need the trailing /index. Without it, it does not work. I have tried to add "'action' => 'index'" to the route, but this did not help